# Why does my Electron app lag after building?

Tags: electron, electron-packager

I have an electron app that works perfectly well when I run it with "npm start". This is my start script:

```
electron .
```

The problem for me is that when I build the program with electron-packager, it behaves abnormally and lags. My build script is below:

```
electron-packager . --overwrite --platform=darwin --arch=x64 --prune=true --out=
release-builds
```

I'm not really sure what's causing the slow behavior in my app. Additionally my app uses WebGL, so I was unable to use the "disableHardwareAcceleration()" command. I'm just confused in general as to why my app functions normally with "npm start", but then lags when I build it into an actual application.

Thank you for any help in advance!

Comment: This could be caused by any of your dependencies. It might be worth running an electron debug on your build to see what is causing the lag. A similar thing happened to me when using RXDB in production environment. I only found this out by running a debug.